# Django: How to prevent a page from reloading when I click button with Ajax/Javascript? (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, ajax

**Premise: A question that can be useful to many. Fetch instead of Ajax. Today Ajax is often replaced by the newer [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in Javascript, which provides a better alternative. If you're looking for a way to avoid page reloading, I recommend using Fetch in pure Javascript. Ajax is still used and still great, but Fetch offers a more modern solution.**

In the `home.html page` (index.html > login.html > home.html) i have a:

- `combobox` (independent, not connected to the database but to a list);
- `textarea`;
- `button`;

When i click the button, it prints some text in the textarea (using a condition found in `views.py`). Very simple.

**Problem:** The problem is that when i click the button, the page reloads and then prints in the textarea. How can I prevent the page from reloading, with Ajax/Javascript, when i click the button (without using jQuery)? Thank you all!

**Important:** bearing in mind that I will have to add many comboboxes, so I would like to manage them as best as possible. Is it possible to manage the code as much as possible in the py files and not split it too much in the js file or js tag?

**P.S:** I searched many questions on stackoverflow or various tutorials, but I couldn't solve. Apparently, even though these are similar questions, each solution is a different case with different problems and solutions.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you all!

**CODE**

**home.html (index > login > home)**

index.html is `127.0.0.1:8000/`. Home.html will only open after successful login. The address of when I view the forms is `127.0.0.1:8000/home` and when I click Submit I still get 127.0.0.1:8000/home (rightfully so). Obviously I wrote the html in a reduced and shorter way:

```
{% extends 'app1/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form action="" method="POST" novalidate class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="color" class="form-select" >
          {% for i in color_choices %}
          <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="msg" cols="30" rows="10">{{message}}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content%}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def home(request):
  color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black","Orange")
  message =''
  if request.method =="POST":
    picked = request.POST.get('color')
    if picked == 'Red':
      message = "<<< You chose red"
      print(message)
    elif picked == 'Blue':
        message = "<<< You chose blue"
    elif picked == 'Black':
        message = "<<< You chose black"
    else:
        message = "<<< Oh no, you chose orange"
  context = {'message':message,'color_choices':color_choices}
  return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class SimpleCombobox(forms.Form):
    Col1 = 'Red'
    Col2 = 'Blue'
    Col3 = 'Black'
    Col4 = 'Orange'
      
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (Col1, u"Red"),
        (Col2, u"Blue"),
        (Col3, u"Black"),
        (Col4, u"Orange"),
    )
    cities = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)


class SimpleTextbox(forms.Form):
    coverletter = forms.CharField(required=False,
              widget=forms.Textarea(
                # rows and colums of the textarea
                attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
    

#LOGIN
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=65)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=65, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: You might want to look at e.g. https://htmx.org/ to help you here.

Comment: @AKX 
I looked at the link, but I didn't understand very well. I'm new to Django. Would you be so kind as to help me with an answer please? Thank you

Comment: use mouse click event to prevent reload a page refresh

Comment: @A.ANoman Can you show me that in an answer please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically by blocking the default click handling by using [`.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault#blocking_default_click_handling). Then you can send a `post` request using the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and for that you will need to [`retrieve csrftoken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) from cookies and set it on the [`request headers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). Here is an example:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form action="" method="POST" novalidate class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select id="select-color" name="color" class="form-select" >
          {% for i in color_choices %}
          <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <textarea id="text-message" class="form-control" name="msg" cols="30" rows="10">{{message}}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" id="button-submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function getCookie(name) {
    ...
  }

  async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
      const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      return response.json();
  }

  document.getElementById("button-submit").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const selected_color = document.getElementById("select-color").value;
    postData(url="{% url 'fetch-message' %}", {color: selected_color})
    .then((response) => { 
      document.getElementById("text-message").innerHTML = response.message
     });
    });
</script>
{% endblock content%}
```

You could do it in just one view, but it is good practice to keep them apart:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
  color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black","Orange")

  context = {'color_choices':color_choices}
  return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)

def fetch_message(request):
  data = json.loads(request.body)
  picked = data['color']
  message = ''

  if picked == 'Red':
    message = "<<< You chose red"
  elif picked == 'Blue':
      message = "<<< You chose blue"
  elif picked == 'Black':
      message = "<<< You chose black"
  else:
      message = "<<< Oh no, you chose orange"

  return JsonResponse({'message': message})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('fetch/message/', fetch_message, name='fetch-message'),
]
```

What is important is `name='fetch-message'`, so that we can reverse resolve the URL on the `template` with `{% url 'fetch-message' %}`.

Comment: In function getCookie what should I write? What is it for? I read that you left the ellipsis (...)

Comment: I get error: NoReverseMatch at /home/
Reverse for 'fetch-message' not found. 'fetch-message' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: `getCookie` is in the reference link on how to `retrieve csrftoken`. It is used to retrieve the `csrftoken` from cookies to later add it to the request `header`. `fetch-message` is a name used for [`reverse resolution`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) (the `name` argument on your `path`) e.g. `path('fetch/message/', fetch_message, name='fetch-message')` that points to your `view`.

Comment: Okay. So in the function getCookie function I have to write something or I have to leave it empty? Also, why am I getting NoReverseMatch error in /home/ Reverse for 'fetch-message' not found. Is 'fetch-message' not a valid view function or model name? Thank you

Comment: One more time, here is the [function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax). As for `NoReverseMatch`, it is happening because your do not have an `URL` as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: I understood the reasoning, but I'm new to Django and didn't understand how to fix it. So in function getCookie I have to paste what is in your link function. While for NoReverseMatch, what URL should I have? The path to the page is app1/home.html, but I'm not sure if you're referring to this. Could you edit your answer showing me how to fix it? I will be happy to accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes paste the code. For the `URL`, you can have any `path` you want, let the framework reverse resolve it for you, meaning `path('any/path/you/want/', fetch_message, name='fetch-message')`. I will update the answer with `urls.py`.

Comment: Ah ok, you were referring to urlpatterns in urls.py. I didn't realize you were referring to it. I was thinking url in postData(url="{% url 'fetch-message' %}". After applying your new change, I get an error in urls.py. The error is: path('fetch/message/' , fetch_message, name='fetch-message'),
NameError: name 'fetch_message' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I just had to import fetch_message with import fetch_message. Anyway this method you used to avoid page reload...is it Ajax, pure Javascript or something else? (I ask to understand what I'm using in order to further my studies). Thank you

Comment: It is all pure JS. But, I think you are mistaking concepts [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is a type of request, which I replaced for `Fetch` which is the newer version.

Comment: I upvoted your answer! All right. I will use your code to further study. Thank you. A curiosity: is it possible to remove the fetch_message function and write its code inside the home function? In order to combine the two functions and enclose everything in a code. I don't like the idea of using color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black","Orange") inside the home function, and then the conditions inside the fetch_message function. If I use many comboboxes, this division is confusing

Comment: As I stated in my answer: `You could do it in just one view, but it is good practice to keep them apart`. Also, requests like this are used for partial update so you do not reload your page entirely.